# Passing contents of CSV file to script function as arguments using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, scripting

I created a CSV file, no headers, two columns per row. I.e.:
ARG001,ARG001a
ARG002,ARG002a
ARG003,ARG003a

I can read it and print out a specific row of the array:

```
require 'csv'
data = CSV.read("recTest.csv")
print data[0]
```

With my output looking like this:

> ["ARG001", "ARG001a"]

What I am trying to do is pass as many rows of data to a function that'll use them within the query string of a URL. I.e.:

> start firefox
> https://desiredSite.com/status?queryStringArg1=ARG001&querySTringArg2=ARG001a

Extremely new with Ruby, any help would be great. Thx in advance!

Comment: Why are you using CSV for this? Why can't you split or deconstruct the lines read in? What have you tried, and why isn't that working for you?

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking. Are you asking how to generate an array of URLs, each with two query string parameters, based on this CSV? Or also how to run some `start firefox` command for each URL?

Comment: Henrik - how to generate the array of url's., I think I think I can figure out how to run ff using system().